# random string of paticular weight

Tags: algorithms

Are there any good classical algorithms which produce strings with length $n$ and have hamming weight $k$? What is the best complexity one can get?

Comment: See Knuth's Algorithm S from section 3.4.2 of "The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2: Seminumerical Algorithms".  You can find code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311703/algorithm-for-sampling-without-replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ross Millikan's suggestion is good, but if $k$ is not too large, the simplest and quickest thing you can do is:

```
b ← 00000.....0
do k times:
  do:
    r ← random(n)  -- select random number between 1 and n
  until b[r] == 0
  b[r] ← 1
done
return b
```

That is, just locate a random unset bit of $b$, set it, and repeat this $k$ times.

This will work well and it should be practical unless $k$ and $n$ are both very large.  It costs next to nothing to try out, so you should try it to see if it is practical before you do anything more complicated. There is a lot to be said in favor of simple algorithms over complex ones. Depending on $n$ and $k$, you might finish running this one before you got a more complicated algorithm written and tested.

The running time here is $O(k)$ if $k\ll n$; the added time from retrying the choice in the inner loop is on the order of $\frac{k^2} n$.

If you want to list *all* the words of weight $k$, that is a different matter.  In general it will take a long time, because in general there are a lot of words.  (${n\choose n/2}$ is exponential in $n$.) I think you can enumerate all of them in time close to $O(k)$ per word using an obvious algorithm, but  you may want to consult the relevant section of Knuth volume 4.

Comment: Another (poorer) approach to generate a random string: generate the string with $k$ $1$s and $n-k$ $0$s, then perform a [random shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) of this list. And I was going to mention Knuth Volume 4... I think the relevant section is Volume 4, Section 7.2.1.3 ("Generating all combinations"), aka Fascicle 3A.

Comment: I kinda like SreevatsaR's answer! Thanks! also MJD, the strings im trying to generate as for example with n=50 and k=1..49, so basically it does get really huge when k=20 odd, when there are exponential number of strings with hamming weight 20 right? In that case does your algorithm still work in O(n) time? Or could i simply apply ShreevatsaR's algorithm and perform any shuffle?

Comment: There is no case in which ShreevatsaR's algorithm is superior to the one I suggested.  n=50 is very small, not very large.  I did not describe an algorithm for enumerating all the words with weight $k$; I described an algorithm for generating one of those words at random. There is obviously *no* algorithm for quickly enumerating all the strings with $n=50$ and $k=20$ because there are 47129212243960 of them. The best you can do is to enumerate them in a small amount of time *per item*. You asked for an algorithm to produce strings of that form quickly and that is what I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest one (ignoring the word random in the title, which is not in the body) is to output $k\  1$'s followed by $n-k \ 0$'s.

If you want a random one, there are $n \choose k$ strings of this sort, so choose a random integer in the range $[0, {n \choose k}-1]$.  If you imagine them sorted in lexicographic order, the first ${n-1 \choose k}$ of them start with $0$, the rest start with $1$.  You can determine the whole string from the random.

Comment: if i was looking to enlist all possible combinations of strings with hamming weight $k$, would this work?

Comment: Yes.  That is the point of saying that is how many there are.  Then the random number picks a particular one.  I show how to start changing the number into a string, and leave getting the rest of the bits to you.  You do it the same way.

Comment: what is the time it takes for this algorithm to solve the problem?

Comment: I think it is dominated by calculating the binomial coefficients.  How many of them do you have to do?  The size gets smaller as you go along.

Comment: As it happens, I implemented this algorithm in Perl a couple of years back. It is useful if you want to generate the words as they are demanded, rather than all at once, since you need only to store the index of the last-generated word, and increment the index each time you generate a new word. Here is the link, in case OP reads Perl: https://github.com/mjdominus/perl-misc/blob/master/Iterator/Subsets/BySize.pm Calculating the binomial coefficients can easily be done in amortized constant time per coefficient.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, MJD I shall definitely have a look into your script! i have commented on your answer as well